# Записывать видео с камеры в фрагменте

Tags: android, android-studio, видео, android-camera

У меня есть приложение, отслеживающее местоположение на карте. Хочу в левом углу добавить запись видео с камеры наподобие видеорегистратора. Как это сделать?

Я пробовал этот пример https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video. Он исправно работает на некоторых девайсах, но крашится на других при вызове метода startRecordingVideo().

```
private void startRecordingVideo() {
    if (null == mCameraDevice || !mTextureView.isAvailable() || null == mPreviewSize) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        removeOldFiles();
        closePreviewSession();
        setUpMediaRecorder();
        SurfaceTexture texture = mTextureView.getSurfaceTexture();
        assert texture != null;
        texture.setDefaultBufferSize(mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
        mPreviewBuilder = mCameraDevice.createCaptureRequest(CameraDevice.TEMPLATE_RECORD);
        List<Surface> surfaces = new ArrayList<>();

        // Set up Surface for the camera preview
        Surface previewSurface = new Surface(texture);
        surfaces.add(previewSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(previewSurface);

        // Set up Surface for the MediaRecorder
        Surface recorderSurface = mMediaRecorder.getSurface();
        surfaces.add(recorderSurface);
        mPreviewBuilder.addTarget(recorderSurface);

        // Start a capture session
        // Once the session starts, we can update the UI and start recording



        /**************************************
        * Приложение крашится на этом моменте *
        **************************************/
        mCameraDevice.createCaptureSession(surfaces, new CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {

            @Override
            public void onConfigured(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                mPreviewSession = cameraCaptureSession;
                updatePreview();
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // UI
                        mIsRecordingVideo = true;
                        // Start recording
                        mMediaRecorder.start();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onConfigureFailed(@NonNull CameraCaptureSession cameraCaptureSession) {
                Activity activity = getActivity();
                if (null != activity) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }, mBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (CameraAccessException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Логи

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.android, PID: 2901
              java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown error -19
                  at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyExceptionUtils.throwOnError(LegacyExceptionUtils.java:69)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.getSurfaceSize(LegacyCameraDevice.java:540)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.LegacyCameraDevice.configureOutputs(LegacyCameraDevice.java:307)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.legacy.CameraDeviceUserShim.endConfigure(CameraDeviceUserShim.java:483)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.utils.Decorator.invoke(Decorator.java:80)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:393)
                  at $Proxy2.endConfigure(Unknown Source)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.configureStreamsChecked(CameraDeviceImpl.java:435)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSessionInternal(CameraDeviceImpl.java:561)
                  at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.createCaptureSession(CameraDeviceImpl.java:476)
                  at com.example.android.views.Camera2VideoFragment.startRecordingVideo(Camera2VideoFragment.java:594)
                  at com.example.views.Camera2VideoFragment.onClick(Camera2VideoFragment.java:324)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

При дебаги, но эти ошибки есть и в оригинальном примере:

```
No such instance field: 'mCameraDevice'
No such instance field: 'mBackgroundHandler'
No such instance field: 'mPreviewBuilder'
```

Comment: Добавте то, что вы попробовали прямо в вопрос.